# Is L and P the same for OAEP in CMS

Tags: rsa, pkcs1

In *RFC 4055 Additional Algorithms* the application of *PKCS#1 2.1 RSAES-OAEP (RFC 3446)* for key transport is described.

The (key transport) parameters of RSAES-OAEP in this RFC define a *hash function*, a parameterized *mask generation function* as well as the *p source function*.

However I cannot find a definite definition of this `P` parameter. Its characteristics (by default an empty string, alternate values for each encryption, input to RSAES-OEAP) suggest that this is the same parameter as called `L` in *RFC 3447*. This is also enforced by the security reflection, which defines the hash beeing applied to *encoding parameter P* (which is done to the L label).

So my question, why does *RFC 4055* not use the cleaner `L` parameter name (less conflicts with RSA's `p`) and is there any formal link of the both I have missed? (*RFC5652 CMS* does not seem to talk about the details of key transport encryption).

Comment: better at crypto?

Comment: Yeah, it seemed too applied, too. I'll see if I can get a crypto mod to look at it and make the call.

Comment: PKCS1 **v2.0** (rfc 2437) called it P; PKCS1 v2.1 changed it to L, but the ASN.1 had already been published and implemented as psource and pspecified/empty and it would have been disruptive to change that. Although published after 2.1, 4055 may well have been in preparation earlier and picked up the old terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PKCS1 v2.0 in 1998 (rfc2437) called it P for encoding parameters; PKCS1 v2.1 in 2003 (rfc3447) changed it to L for label, but the ASN.1 had already been published and implemented using names like `pSourceAlgorithm id-pSpecified pSpecifiedEmpty` and it would have been disruptive to change that. This is noted in [the description of `pSourceAlgorithm` in A.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#appendix-A.2)

Although rfc4055 was published after 2.1 in 2005, since it is Standards Track work on it would probably have started earlier, apparently by enough to pick up the old terminology. It does reference 3447, but updating references is usually among the final steps done by the RFC editor. OTOH 2437 and 3447 are only Informational copies of documents from (then) RSALabs and could have moved faster because they didn't need consensus.

Comment: Thank you, makes sense. I got basically the same response when filling an errata, which might end up as an editorial fix. http://www.rfc-editor.org/errata/eid5199